# Nested selectors with less points to top most selector in sourcemap

Tags: less, source-maps

I like nesting my selectors with less for clarity of code / organization etc.

However after compiling (In this instance I am using gulp-less) and using Firefox or Chrome Developer tools to determine the line number of my selector, it will point to the top most selector.

If there is a large chunk of selectors encapsulated this can be a waste of time to even bother looking up the line number because it will give you the top selector encasing the code.

eg. here is my header.less:

```
 #header-master{
    background: @brand-primary url("@{img-dir}background.jpg?v=2") no-repeat;
    min-height: 117px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;

    &:after{
        width: 416px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 7px;
        content: " ";
        background: white;
        z-index: 1000;
        @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
            max-width: 322px;
        }
        @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
            max-width: 201px;
        }
        @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
            height: 0px;
            display:none;
        }   
    }


    @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
        padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width /2 );
    }

    @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
        background: @brand-primary url("@{img-dir}header-bg-sm.jpg?v=2") no-repeat; 
    }

    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {

        min-height: 70px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    #logo{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
    #royal-warrant{
        margin-top: 2px;
    }

    #header-middle{
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
        min-height: 109px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 603px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 91px;
        position: relative;

        @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
            max-width: 424px;
        }
        @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
            max-width: 201px;
        }

        @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
            max-width: none;
            margin-right: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            left: 93px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        &:before{
            width: 69px;
            left: -69px;
            content: " ";
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            background: url("@{img-dir}left-header-edge.png") no-repeat;
            min-height: 109px;

        }

        &:after{
            width: 64px;
            right: -64px;
            content: " ";
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            background: url("@{img-dir}right-header-edge.png") no-repeat;
            min-height: 109px;

        }

        @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {

            &:after{
                width: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                background: none;
            }
        }

        #header-search{
            margin-top: 20px;
            max-width: 518px;
            margin-left: 4px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1000;
            overflow: hidden;

            @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
                margin-left: -13px;
                max-width: 431px;
            }
            @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
                margin-top: 17px;
                margin-left: -22px;
            }

            > .input-group{
                width: 511px;
                z-index: 1000;

                @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
                    width: 431px;   
                }

                @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
                    width: 221px;
                }
            }

            label, #header-search-label{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 1000;
                padding: 4px;
                font-weight: normal;
                max-width: 490px;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 23px;
                font-size: 12.2px;
                padding-left: 7px;
                display: none; // display with javascript 
            }

            input{
                font-size: 12.5px;
            }


            #header-search-links{
                z-index: 1000;
                position: relative;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding-top: 8px;
                padding-left: 5px;

                li{

                    font-size: 11px;
                    font-weight: bold;

                    a{
                        text-decoration: underline;
                        color: @brand-info;

                        &:hover{
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: @brand-primary;
                        }
                    }
                }

                li.active{

                    a{
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: @brand-primary;
                    }
                }
            }

            #search-text-under{
                padding-top: @vert-padding;
                float: right;
            }

        }
    }

    #header-right{

        @media (min-width: @screen-sm) {
            max-width: 136px;
            float: right;
        }

        @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
            z-index: 3000;
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 140px;
            height: 68px;
            right: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 10px;

        }

        ol, ul, #header-links-top{
            margin-bottom: 2px;

            li{
                &:last-child{
                    padding-right: 0px;
                }
            }
        }

        #header-basket-checkout{
            clear: right;
            margin-top: 10px;
            float: right;
            min-width: 110px;
            line-height: 0.95em;
            text-align: right;
        }

        #header-mobile-buttons{
            .fa-lg{
                font-size: 1.8em;
            }
            .fa-search{
                font-size: 1.3em;
            }

            .btn-default{
                line-height: 1.1em;
            }
        }

        #header-basket-button{
            margin-top: -7px;
            margin-right: -2px;
        }

    }

    #secondary-menu{
        position: absolute;
        height: 27px;
        bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left:53px;
        font-family: arimo;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-top: 2px solid @brand-primary;
        border-right: 2px solid @brand-primary;
        border-left: 2px solid @brand-primary;
        @media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
            left: -63px;
            margin-left: 0;
            z-index:1000;
        }
        @media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
            left: -166px;
        }

        @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
            margin-left: -14px;
            z-index: 1000;
            margin-top: 46px;
            font-size: 13px;
            border-top: 0;
            border-right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        ul{
            margin: 0;
            background: @brand-primary;

            li{
                background: @brand-primary;
                position: relative;
                padding: 3px 12px 3px 6px;
                margin: 0px;
                float: left;

                &:before{
                    content: " ";
                    position: absolute;
                    left: -4px;
                    bottom: -2px;
                    border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
                    height: 22px;
                    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
                    z-index: 100;
                }   

                &:first-child{
                    &:before{
                        bottom: 0px; // Petes Design
                    }
                    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
                        &:before{
                            border-right: none;
                            background: none;
                        }
                    }
                }

                a{
                    color: white;
                }
                &:last-child{
                    padding: 3px 10px 3px 6px;

                }


            }
            li.active{

                background: white;

                a{
                    color: @brand-primary;
                    vertical-align: -4px;
                }


                &:before{
                    border-right: 5px solid #FFF;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    height: auto;

                }
                /*border: 3px solid @brand-primary;*/
            }

        }
    }

}


.ie8 #header-master{
    min-height: 110px;
}
```

So If I wanted to get the line number of #secondary-menu, developer tools will point to header.less file line number 1 because the encapsulating selector is #header-master.

This is obviously logical but not useful if we are looking to get the actual line numbers. Does anyone know if there is a tool / way to compile etc to get the actual line numbers without having to not use nesting?

Also I notice that it does give the correct line numbers when there is a media query being used. So the sourcemap knows where the actual line numbers are it just doesn't translate to developer tools.

Comment: Known Less/Chrome issue [#1492](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1492). In short: Less creates individual source map entries for each element of the selector but browsers use only line mapping of its first element.

Comment: Yes true, I primarily use Fire Fox not Chrome for development. I was looking for a fix to get line numbers. I may just have to not use such large nesting.